# MySQL reporting query

Tags: mysql

I have the following db schema (i'm only mentioning the columns for each table necessary for the query in mind):

```
bills
-------
id
amount (decimal)
collection_case_id


collection_case
------------------
id


payments
----------
id
bill_id
amount (decimal)
type (char(2)) - "CH" stands for check payment, field used for polymorphism 

check_payments
---------------
payment_id
```

For a set of collection cases, I need to get the total interest earned from check payments.
I am currently doing these calculations in memory after retrieving all the bill records for my set of collection case criteria.  For each bill I simply add the sum of checks received -   bill amount if sum of checks received is greater than bill amount.

for instance my total received query looks like this (collection cases 1 & 2):

```
select sum(payment.amount) as received 
from bills bill
cross join payments payment inner join check_payments checkpayment 
on 
payment.id=checkpayment.payment_id 
where payment.type='CH'
 and payment.bill_id=bill.id 
 and (bill.collection_case_id in (1 , 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if this is what you meant.

```
select IF(sum(payment.amount) > bill.amount, sum(payment.amount)-bill.amount, 0) as interest  
from bills bill
cross join payments payment inner join check_payments checkpayment 
on 
payment.id=checkpayment.payment_id 
where payment.type='CH'
 and payment.bill_id=bill.id 
 and (bill.collection_case_id in (1 , 2))
```

Comment: Just tried it, giving wrong results, maybe the sum(payment.amount) is the sum of all payments for all the bills that are in collection cases 1 & 2? I need it to check if the amount of each bill is < the sum of all payments for the specific bill

Comment: if the result you want do not limit to collection cases 1 & 2, you could remove that criteria.

Comment: I do..thats not what I meant, (1,2) is for example, the user selects the collection cases..but it seems that the query sum(payment.amount) > bill.amount test fails to do what I intend..I think it sums up the payments for all bills and then tests it for each individual bill

Comment: Case 1: total bill amount - 87.20, received - 161, interest - 117.40, Case 2: total bill amount - 160.04, received - 30, interest - 0, and the query you have recommended gives total interest as 147.40 and its suppose to be 117.40

Comment: Could you post with some sample data @ sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19914/9  i use subquery to sum up the total interest. this will give an accurate figure for this. However, i still cannot figure how the 147.40  results in.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19914/11  modified on the group by clause. I think should be more appropriate to group by bill_id instead.

Comment: its adding the $30 for bill 19 although the received is less then the amount for this bill

Comment: You are genious! Thank you so much!!! Would it be possible to get the total received and total amount in the same query?

Comment: I've added received to your sqlfiddle..but don't know how to get the right results for total bill amount

Comment: isn't the total bill amount = 123.62?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17840/discussion-between-sel-and-user979051)